# removing link on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a div which I want to hide when the screen is mobile size. Currently I have

html

```
<div id='top-btn'>
    <a class="fade-in" href="...">Top</a>
</div>
```

css

```
#top-btn a {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  ...
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

#top-btn a { display: none; }

}
```

The div is hidden but the button is still there, so there's an area that still links (clickable). I want it to be completely gone so they can't click on it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lrmgrpq/ your code is working as expected (no clickable area at less than `768px` wide) on OSX Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the whole button, rather than just the link itself:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #top-btn { display: none; }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me the code works..without any changes.
Maybe your browser don't support @Media,
Here you can check what browsers support this command
Link: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

but before checking the link,try this..

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

#top-btn , .fade-in { display: none; }

}
```

Comment: ahh perfect that fixed it!